# Where to buy and how to replace missing piece antique french hunters cabinet?

Tags: furniture, wood-repair

I have an Antique French Hunters Cabinet in which the top molding is missing.  See picture below which shows the piece before the top piece of molding was lost.  Where would I buy a piece of wood  molding to replicate the trim and how would I age and stain the wood so it matches the existing piece?  I have tried to go to my local Home depot and lowes and they don't have the inventory.  I would really appreciate any help you could provide. 
Thanks
 .[image]

Comment: As a rule you'd have to be very *very* lucky to find what's necessary to restore a piece like this in HD or similar :-| This is a fine antique, not exactly in the remit of stores like this! You can go to a custom millwork supplier who can make up mouldings that match old profiles but in all honestly I think the entire job should be handed over to a competent restorer. In either case I think there's going to be some discomfort at the cost, but this is a valuable piece so probably worth it.

Comment: *"how would I age and stain the wood so it matches the existing piece?"* As a general thing this sort of question is outside the scope of this SE (and actually any online forum to be honest). We, and any other forum members, give generic advice on how you might go about this *sort* of job, but that doesn't help with every specific case and the advice comes with no warranty. The exact steps necessary for success here could involve one or two things not covered generically. Success here I would define as, it's impossible to tell the moulding is a replacement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a product or vendor recommendation: "where can I buy xxx?"

Comment: A better question for this forum might be "How can I reproduce a particular contour of molding" or "How can I carve a decorative element like <photo>".  Also, from the original photo I can't tell what exactly is missing.

Comment: Closed as off-topic due to reading as a purchasing recommendation. Please edit the question to either ask for high-level recommendations on how to assess and restore a piece of antique furniture, or how to reproduce a specific component, as SaSSafraS1232 suggested. Matching the appearance (color, finish, etc.) could be one or more separate questions, although as Graphus pointed out, we would only be able to provide generic advice.

Comment: Come on @Rob.  OP is asking "How do I do it?" and "Home Depot is a miss, so where do I look?"  A product recommendation is not requested.  I don't have an answer for OP, but I am certain there are individuals who can make recommendations beyond, "find a professional to do it."  This is a challenging project; let us not discourage the submission of a good answer.

Comment: I agree that this *could* be a good question, but it is not clear to me OP wants or is able to do the kind of work it would take. If OP changes it to indicate they are wanting to do the work themselves, then I'd be all for reopening it.

Comment: @AstPace I agree this has the makings of an excellent question, but it is not quite there yet.